# Xcode Dismiss Keyboard Login Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I'm working on an application that has a functioning keyboard with editing capabilities. In the mainViewController.m file, I am able to properly hide the keyboard with the following line of code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

After completing the main functionality of the application, I've created a simple login screen. However, the same code as above is not working in the loginScreen.m file.

```
@implementation LoginScreen



-(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(IBAction)btnLoginRegisterTapped:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //form fields validation
    if (fldUsername.text.length < 4 || fldPassword.text.length < 4) {
        [UIAlertView error:@"Enter username and password over 4 chars each."];
        return;
    }

//salt the password
NSString* saltedPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fldPassword.text, kSalt];

// Check for name/pw length

//prepare the hashed storage
NSString* hashedPassword = nil;
unsigned char hashedPasswordData[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

//hash the pass
NSData *data = [saltedPassword dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hashedPasswordData)) {
    hashedPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:hashedPasswordData length:sizeof(hashedPasswordData) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
} else {
    [UIAlertView error:@"Password can't be sent"];
    return;
}

//check whether it's a login or register
NSString* command = (sender.tag==1)?@"register":@"login";
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              command, @"command",
                              fldUsername.text, @"username",
                              hashedPassword, @"password",
                              nil];

//make the call to the web API
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {


                               //result returned
                               NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];

                               if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil && [[res objectForKey:@"IdUser"] intValue]>0) {
                                   [[API sharedInstance] setUser: res];
                                   [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   //show message to the user
                                   [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in"
                                                               message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[res objectForKey:@"username"] ]
                                                              delegate:nil 
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" 
                                                     otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

                               } else {
                                   //error
                                   [UIAlertView error:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
                               }



                           }];



}

@end
```

If I figure out the fix, I'll add it here but I'm not sure what is causing this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @zaph Thank you for your response. I am aware that Xcode does not run the app as I have various iOS devices for testing.

Comment: A simple "I think you may have an error in the question title" may have been more helpful.

Comment: Returned to the original title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tap gesture to hide keyboard

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}



-(void)tapReceived:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];

}
```